# An induction proof in a set.

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I have an induction problem that I have no idea how to start. So the question goes like this.

Let $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$ and $x_n=x_{n-1} + 2x_{n-2}$.

Prove that $x_n=2^{n-1}$ for all $n$ in the natural numbers.

I know the base case is true but after that I do not know what to do. I do not want the answer, but rather a guide on the first few steps. I do not understand induction on sets like this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This surely is a duplicate.

Comment: Check my edit please.

Comment: Suppose that the statement is true for $n-2$ and $n-1$. Then can you prove that it is true for $n$?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Currently I am in class, but will respond again when I work through the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it by induction. You checked base cases, so now you should prove induction.

$$ \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\right)\left(\left(x_n = 2^{n-1} \wedge x_{n+1} = 2^{(n+1)-1} \right)\Rightarrow x_{n+2}=2^{(n+2)-1}\right) \Longleftrightarrow \\
\left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\right)\left(\underbrace{x_n = 2^{n-1} \wedge x_{n+1} = 2^{n}}_{\mathrm{Assumption}} \Rightarrow \underbrace{x_{n+2}=2^{n+1}}_{\mathrm{Thesis}}\right)$$

From $x_n = x_{n-1}+2 x_{n-2}$ and assumptionis easy to obtain $x_{n+2} = 2^{n+1}$

$$x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} + 2 \cdot x_{n} = 2^{n} + 2^{1} \cdot 2^{{n-1}} =
2^{n} + 2^{n-1+1} = 2 \cdot 2^{n} = 2^{n+1}$$

Which proves the inductive thesis. 
By virtue of the above steps and mathematical induction...

In fact, it will be more elegant if you prove$\left(x_{n-2} = 2^{n-3} \wedge  x_{n-1} = 2^{n-2} \Rightarrow x_{n} = 2^{n-1}\right)$, but I believe you can modify it by your own.